# How to detect build server runs?

Tags: codenameone

As described in the blog post [THE 7 SCREENSHOTS OF IOS](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/the-7-screenshots-of-ios.html) with an IOS build a Codename One app is run on the build server to create screen shots for the possible resolutions of devices.

I would like to detect whether the app runs on the build server. Is that possible and what way of detecting that would You recommend?

Comment: Display.getInstance().getProperty("OS", "unknown").equals("SE") && !Display.getInstance().isSimulator() ?

Comment: I suggest asking with a use case explaining what you are trying to do as there are **several** approaches to solve issues related to the screenshot process and none of them are about the detection of the build server which is a flaky proposition

Comment: My main reason is to start up as fast as possible but still indicate to the user that the app is not ready yet. Therefore I want to display sort of a splash screen only in the build server screenshot process.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest enclosing screenshots in the native iOS directory as explained in [this developer guide section](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/appendix-ios.html). It would probably be the simplest solution.